# Thrift alternative for HBase?

Tags: php, database, nosql, hbase

We are having trouble with reading data in PHP using Thrift for HBase. Loading data, creating tables is all good. Problem are the rest of data operations. There isn't much documentation for this apart from their main website hence lost. All the tutorials I've seen on the net deal with setup & inserting data, not other data operations.

In interest of time we are looking for alternatives to thrift that can help PHP & HBase work + has enough documentation. If we can't find alternatives then the plan is to use Cassandra instead of HBase until better documentation is out there for HBase with PHP. But any suggestions for in-depth tutorials or alternates to make PHP & HBase work for all data operations would be great.

Comment: What are exactly data operations that are missing from PHP Thrift?

Answer (score 1):

Beside Thrift HBase also supports [REST interface](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate) which might provide some other ways to access data. Note that REST interface is slower by design because it uses HTTP, not Thrift protocol.

Answer (score 0):

They have client examples in the source code:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/trunk/src/examples/thrift/